# Pagination response payload from a RESTful API

Tags: rest, pagination

I want to support pagination in my RESTful API.

My API method should return a JSON list of product via `/products/index`. However, there are potentially thousands of products, and I want to page through them, so my request should look something like this:

```
/products/index?page_number=5&page_size=20
```

But what does my JSON response need to look like? Would API consumers typically expect pagination meta data in the response? Or is only an array of products necessary? Why?

It looks like Twitter's API includes meta data: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/members (see Example Request).

With meta data:

```
{
  "page_number": 5,
  "page_size": 20,
  "total_record_count": 521,
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Widget #1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Widget #2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Widget #3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just an array of products (no meta data):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Widget #1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Widget #2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Widget #3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

ReSTful APIs are consumed primarily by other systems, which is why I put paging data in the response headers. However, some API consumers may not have direct access to the response headers, or may be building a UX over your API, so providing a way to retrieve (on demand) the metadata in the JSON response is a plus.

I believe your implementation should include machine-readable metadata as a default, and human-readable metadata when requested. The human-readable metadata could be returned with every request if you like or, preferably, on-demand via a query parameter, such as `include=metadata` or `include_metadata=true`.

In your particular scenario, I would include the URI for each product with the record. This makes it easy for the API consumer to create links to the individual products. I would also set some reasonable expectations as per the limits of my paging requests. Implementing and documenting default settings for page size is an acceptable practice. For example, [GitHub's API](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) sets the default page size to 30 records with a maximum of 100, plus sets a rate limit on the number of times you can query the API. If your API has a default page size, then the query string can just specify the page index.

In the human-readable scenario, when navigating to `/products?page=5&per_page=20&include=metadata`, the response could be:

```
{
  "_metadata": 
  {
      "page": 5,
      "per_page": 20,
      "page_count": 20,
      "total_count": 521,
      "Links": [
        {"self": "/products?page=5&per_page=20"},
        {"first": "/products?page=0&per_page=20"},
        {"previous": "/products?page=4&per_page=20"},
        {"next": "/products?page=6&per_page=20"},
        {"last": "/products?page=26&per_page=20"},
      ]
  },
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Widget #1",
      "uri": "/products/1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Widget #2",
      "uri": "/products/2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Widget #3",
      "uri": "/products/3"
    }
  ]
}
```

For machine-readable metadata, I would add [Link headers](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988.txt) to the response:

```
Link: </products?page=5&perPage=20>;rel=self,</products?page=0&perPage=20>;rel=first,</products?page=4&perPage=20>;rel=previous,</products?page=6&perPage=20>;rel=next,</products?page=26&perPage=20>;rel=last
```

*(the Link header value should be urlencoded)*

...and possibly a custom `total-count` response header, if you so choose:

```
total-count: 521
```

The other paging data revealed in the human-centric metadata might be superfluous for machine-centric metadata, as the link headers let me know which page I am on and the number per page, and I can quickly retrieve the number of records in the array. Therefore, I would probably only create a header for the total count. You can always change your mind later and add more metadata.

*As an aside, you may notice I removed `/index` from your URI. A generally accepted convention is to have your ReST endpoint expose collections. Having `/index` at the end muddies that up slightly.*

These are just a few things I like to have when consuming/creating an API.

Comment: per_page doesn't follow the convention page_size

Comment: `"page_count": 20` and `{"last": "/products?page=26&per_page=20"}`?

Comment: what would happen if the product's count suddenly increase while fetching all the records from page 1 to page x?

Comment: @MeV the same that happens on any cursor-based pagination scenario: total will increase, and page count might increase if the last page is full, nothing more, nothing less. It is a very common scenario on every app that uses this type of pagination. It will depend on the sorting being used if the new product appears on the first or last page.

Comment: what do you mean by machine-readable metadata, is machine-readable metadata the one I access in my client library?

Comment: _"ReSTful APIs are consumed primarily by other systems, which is why I put paging data in the response headers"_ That's like saying it's sunny outside, which is why I'm wearing a blue shirt. What makes you think that headers cannot be read by humans?

Comment: Nice doc about pratical example of pagination  https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: This is the most logical answer that suits both needs. But what do you mean by `ReSTful APIs are consumed primarily by other systems, which is why I put paging data in the response headers`? Could you please elaborate further? Thanks!

Comment: "This makes it easy for the API consumer to create links to the individual products" - Can someone explain to me this or what is the purpose of using "uri" in each record?
Are these links used to navigate to the individual product?

Comment: "_some API consumers [...] may be building a UX over your API_" This mixes up UX with UI, and I think the point is that some UI technology might not be able to consume HTTP headers? That should probably not be a concern nowadays anymore...

Comment: For efficiency, if a frontend app request using the `include=metadata`, should you still include the metadata in the header? Or just move all the metadata to the body? @codeprogression

Comment: I would name "_metadata" "pagination_data" and "records" "products".

Answer (score 45):

I would recommend adding headers for the same. Moving metadata to headers helps in getting rid of envelops like `result` , `data` or `records` and response body only contains the data we need. You can use [Link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader) header if you generate pagination links too.

```
    HTTP/1.1 200
    Pagination-Count: 100
    Pagination-Page: 5
    Pagination-Limit: 20
    Content-Type: application/json

    [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "shirt",
        "color": "red",
        "price": "$23"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "shirt",
        "color": "blue",
        "price": "$25"
      }
    ]
```

For details refer to:

https://github.com/adnan-kamili/rest-api-response-format

For swagger file:

https://github.com/adnan-kamili/swagger-response-template

Comment: Interesting @adnankamili ! If for some reason, we needed to add the pagination metadata and headers, how would you do it?

Comment: This is particularly useful if you already have an API where the data is not already in an envelope, that way you won't have to change every single endpoint. Also metadata is what the header is for, so to me it makes a lot of sense semantically.

Comment: Although I've upvoted Ray's and your comment and answer, I recommend NOT dropping the `X-` because it's utterly confusing, I thought "_Oh there are such HTTP headers_? and I Googled them for a few minutes until I read the comment section. RFCs are great but I think conventions matter a lot too. Also APIs are versioned so if one day a custom header of ours becomes standard we just give the other one as well in our next version. So I recommend putting the "X-"s back.

Comment: The remark about headers makes sense, but returning an object instead of an array would be a more futureproof solution if you ever need to extend the API response. So `{ "data": [ ... ] }` instead of just `[ ]`.

Comment: @vgru future-proofing your API response is a sign of premature optimization. Until such time you know what to extend the responses with, you probably don't need to. That's one of the reasoning why API versioning exists in the first place.

Comment: @MicoFrancisco: future-proofing is a good thing in my book :) But wrapping the response in the `data` fields is pretty common practice (check the JSON:API standard for example).

Answer (score 35):

As someone who has written several libraries for consuming REST services, let me give you the client perspective on why I think wrapping the result in metadata is the way to go:

- Without the total count, how can the client know that it has not yet received everything there is and should continue paging through the result set? In a UI that didn't perform look ahead to the next page, in the worst case this might be represented as a Next/More link that didn't actually fetch any more data.
- Including metadata in the response allows the client to track less state. Now I don't have to match up my REST request with the response, as the response contains the metadata necessary to reconstruct the request state (in this case the cursor into the dataset).
- If the state is part of the response, I can perform multiple requests into the same dataset simultaneously, and I can handle the requests in any order they happen to arrive in which is not necessarily the order I made the requests in.

And a suggestion: Like the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring), you should replace the page_number with a straight index/cursor. The reason is, the API allows the client to set the page size per-request. Is the returned page_number the number of pages the client has requested so far, or the number of the page given the last used page_size (almost certainly the later, but why not avoid such ambiguity altogether)?

Comment: To your first bullet, would it be a suitable solution to omit a rel=next link if there was no next page? To your second bullet, the information is still available in the response to the client, it's just not in the body of the response but instead is in the headers. +1 on your last paragraph.

Comment: I want to answer your suggestion at the end. Cursor pagination is not the same as page/offset pagination. Both have their pros and cons and performance considerations.

Answer (score 2):

just add in your backend API new property's into response body.
from example .net core:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromQuery]UserParams userParams)
{
  var users = await _repo.GetUsers(userParams);
  var usersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserForListDto>>(users);


  // create new object and add into it total count param etc
  var UsersListResult = new
  {
    usersToReturn,
    currentPage = users.CurrentPage,
    pageSize = users.PageSize,
    totalCount = users.TotalCount,
    totalPages = users.TotalPages
  };

  return Ok(UsersListResult);
}
```

[In body response it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg4wG.png)

```
{
"usersToReturn": [
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "username": "nancycaldwell@conjurica.com",
        "firstName": "Joann",
        "lastName": "Wilson",
        "city": "Armstrong",
        "phoneNumber": "+1 (893) 515-2172"
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "username": "zelmasheppard@conjurica.com",
        "firstName": "Booth",
        "lastName": "Drake",
        "city": "Franks",
        "phoneNumber": "+1 (800) 493-2168"
    }
],
// metadata to pars in client side
"currentPage": 1,
"pageSize": 2,
"totalCount": 87,
"totalPages": 44
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is an interessting question and may be perceived with different arguments. As per the general standard meta related data should be communicated in the response headers e.g. MIME type and HTTP codes. However, the tendency I seem to have observed is that information related to counts and pagination typically are communicated at the top of the response body. Just to provide an example of this The New York Times REST API communicate the count at the top of the response body (https://developer.nytimes.com/apis).

The question for me is wheter or not to comply with the general norms or adopt and do a response message construction that "fits the purpose" so to speak. You can argue for both and providers do this differently, so I believe it comes down to what makes sense in your particular context.

As a general recommendation ALL meta data should be communicated in the headers. For the same reason I have upvoted the suggested answer from @adnan kamili.

However, it is not "wrong" to included some sort of meta related information such as counts or pagination in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using one of the common standards to represent a paged response. For example see [HAL's way to represent collections](https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer#collections) where I took this snippet from. It contains:

- `_links`: navigation links: first, last, next & prev
- page info: current page number, page count, page size, total elements
- current page content as `_embedded` list - an array of the items in the page

Framework such as Spring support this format natively and assemble the paged payloads.

```json
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=3"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user"
        },
        "prev": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=2"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=4"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=133"
        }
    },
    "count": 3,
    "total": 498,
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.org/api/user/mwop"
                    }
                },
                "id": "mwop",
                "name": "Matthew Weier O'Phinney"
            },
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.org/api/user/mac_nibblet"
                    }
                },
                "id": "mac_nibblet",
                "name": "Antoine Hedgecock"
            },
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.org/api/user/spiffyjr"
                    }
                },
                "id": "spiffyjr",
                "name": "Kyle Spraggs"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

generally, I make by simple way, whatever, I create a restAPI endpoint for example "localhost/api/method/:lastIdObtained/:countDateToReturn"
with theses parameters, you can do it a simple request.
in the service, eg. .net

```
jsonData function(lastIdObtained,countDatetoReturn){
'... write your code as you wish..'
and into select query make a filter
select top countDatetoreturn tt.id,tt.desc
 from tbANyThing tt
where id > lastIdObtained
order by id
}
```

In Ionic, when I scroll from bottom to top, I pass the zero value, when I get the answer, I set the value of the last id obtained, and when I slide from top to bottom, I pass the last registration id I got

Comment: First and foremost, this does not answer the original question because you do not use pagination with limit and offset. Plus, the question was about RESTful APIs and your approach is not RESTful at all.