# Proper way to respond to a rest paged request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, pagination

I want to create a REST compliant endpoint in Spring. The endpoint is supposed to allow pagination.

The request is quite simple, GET to url/resource?page=1&pageSize=20.
The problem is the request.

I have found 2 big ways of returning the data:

1. Return a custom object containing:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "content": [
         {...},
         {...}
         ...
    ]
}
```

The problem with this method is that it no longer returns a resource, it returns a wrapper to the resource.

2. Set X-Total-Count custom header when you give the response from backend:

```
[
   {...},
   {...}
   ...
]
```

This resolves the resource issue, but it makes the endpoint harder to use, which is counter-intuitive since it requires extra work to implement as well.

I wanted to know, what standards are more widely used and why? What is the "new" approach to this? What should I stay away from? Is there a way to satisfy both needs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination response payload from a RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168624/pagination-response-payload-from-a-restful-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common practice I see in API's I use is your first example with an object wrapper:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "content": [
         {...},
         {...}
         ...
    ]
}
```

Usually, this object wrapper is implemented with any call to a `GET /resources` endpoint. When users call a `GET resource/{resourceId}` endpoint on the other hand, there is no object wrapper.

This is just my opinion relating to what I see other API's use, but I have written close to 100 different API integrations so I have seen a fair amount.