# How to extract the data for this type of Json Array with Newtonsoft Json

Tags: arrays, json, json.net

I am new to JSON in general. I have a JSON file and I want to extract data from it, but I can't seem to find a way on how to do it. I've searched online, but I could not find any answer or I was just looking at the wrong places.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{"data":
    {"cars":
        {"total":117,
        "results":[
            {"id":"779579"},
            {"id":"952209"},
            {"id":"1103285"},
            {"id":"1157321"},
            {"id":"1372321"},
            {"id":"1533192"},
            {"id":"1630240"},
            {"id":"2061824"},
            {"id":"2312383"},
            {"id":"2353755"},
            {"id":"2796716"},
            {"id":"2811260"},
            {"id":"2824839"},
            {"id":"2961828"},
            {"id":"3315226"},
            {"id":"3586555"},
            {"id":"3668182"},
            {"id":"3986886"},
            {"id":"3989623"},
            {"id":"3998581"},
            {"id":"4021057"},
            {"id":"4038880"},
            {"id":"4308809"},
            {"id":"4325718"},
            {"id":"4352725"},
            {"id":"4360349"},
            {"id":"4628661"},
            {"id":"4863093"},
            {"id":"4940146"},
            {"id":"4947395"},
            {"id":"5157781"},
            {"id":"5794466"},
            {"id":"6134469"},
            {"id":"6157337"},
            {"id":"6307352"},
            {"id":"6727975"},
            {"id":"6783794"},
            {"id":"6831800"},
            {"id":"6960771"},
            {"id":"7159286"},
            {"id":"7211880"},
            {"id":"7212277"},
            {"id":"7217410"},
            {"id":"7264660"},
            {"id":"7406984"},
            {"id":"7893798"},
            {"id":"7948268"},
            {"id":"8047751"},
            {"id":"8271106"},
            {"id":"8346001"},
            {"id":"8352176"},
            {"id":"8485193"},
            {"id":"8746468"},
            {"id":"8801718"},
            {"id":"9104008"},
            {"id":"9494179"},
            {"id":"9588599"},
            {"id":"9717878"},
            {"id":"9845048"},
            {"id":"9891941"},
            {"id":"9943516"},
            {"id":"10002374"},
            {"id":"10213949"},
            {"id":"10326370"},
            {"id":"10499431"},
            {"id":"10518069"},
            {"id":"10538037"},
            {"id":"10589618"},
            {"id":"10602337"},
            {"id":"10723171"},
            {"id":"10724725"},
            {"id":"10746729"},
            {"id":"10751575"},
            {"id":"10752559"},
            {"id":"10852235"},
            {"id":"10867573"},
            {"id":"10877115"},
            {"id":"10893349"},
            {"id":"10988880"},
            {"id":"10993485"},
            {"id":"11026957"},
            {"id":"11111205"},
            {"id":"11122085"},
            {"id":"11150052"},
            {"id":"11251748"},
            {"id":"11259887"},
            {"id":"11270391"},
            {"id":"11291731"},
            {"id":"11303142"},
            {"id":"11303143"},
            {"id":"11308615"},
            {"id":"11313379"},
            {"id":"11334337"},
            {"id":"11338119"},
            {"id":"11338290"},
            {"id":"11339650"},
            {"id":"11347202"},
            {"id":"11359983"},
            {"id":"11390048"},
            {"id":"11399541"}]}}}
```

I want to extract all the id and put them in an array. I tried JToken, but it can only get 100 data (up to element [99]) only because anything beyond 99 would give me an error. I tried it using a for loop.

This is the error I get if go beyond 99:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
> Parameter name: index

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: *I tried JToken but it can only get 100 data (up to element [99]) only because anything beyond 99 would give me an error.* -- then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the code that did not work.  Are you sure that your `results` array has more than 99 items?

Comment: In the JSON shown there are only 100 ids, despite the fact that data.cars.total is 117.  Looks like you should ignore the total value and just linq as shown here: `var ids = jtoken.SelectTokens("data.cars.results[*].id").Select(id => (int)id).ToList();`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhY9s1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the value of `data.cars.total` is not what you think it is.  In the JSON shown there are only 100 ids, despite the fact that `data.cars.total` equals 117. To put those 100 ids into an array, you may use [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) along with LINQ's [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) as follows:

```
var jtoken = JToken.Parse(jsonString); // Or load the JSON from a stream
var ids = jtoken.SelectTokens("data.cars.results[*].id").Select(id => (int)id).ToArray(); // Remove the .Select(id => (int)id) if you want them as strings

Console.WriteLine("{0} ids found:", ids.Length); // Prints 100
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ids));        // Prints the deserialized ids
```

Where `[*]` is the [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator selecting all array elements.

Just a guess here, but possibly your JSON reflects a [paged response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12168624) in which `data.cars.total` is the total number of ids, not the number returned in the current page which was limited to 100.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhY9s1).